# Extract controller and action names from ActionResult

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my view (or partial view), I want to use a helper that has this signature:

```
// using T4MVC to get the ActionResult from "MVC.FooController.BarAction()"
@Html.doStuff(MVC.FooController.BarAction(), someData)
```

instead of

```
@Html.doStuff(controllerName, actionName, someData)
```

I want to simplify my extension method, i.e. one argument instead of two.

In the extension method, how would I extract controller and action names from an instance of `ActionResult`?

*Note that `HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();` doesn't help. I need to pass in an arbitrary `ActionResult`. So this is NOT a duplicate question*

Comment: I could take a dependency on T4MVC and use it's extensions to extract this data. But that means my code would be relying on a side effect, and would be brittle.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I've already noted why it's not a dupe. Please remove the dupe heading as it might prevent me from getting people to look at the question and proposing answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `View` use below code -

```
@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"]
@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["Action"]
```

In `Controller` -

```
Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString()
Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString()
```

In C# Helper Class -

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
```

If you want you retrieve Action and controller names from ActionResult, then one option would be -

```
// In Action
 ViewBag.Controller = Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
 ViewBag.Action = Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
```

Then retrieve values from `ActionResult` in following way -

```
var controllerName = actionResultVariable.ViewBag.Controller;
var actionName = actionResultVariable.ViewBag.Action;
```

**EDIT: Option 2 :**

Create a Custom `ActionResult` -

```
public class MyActionResult : ViewResult
    {
        public MyActionResult(object model)
        {
            this.ViewData.Model = model;
        }
        public string ControllerName
        {
            get
            {
                return HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
            }
        }

        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
           base.ExecuteResult(context);
        }
    }
```

And then in your Controller Action -

```
return new MyActionResult(model);
```

Then as you are passing the ActionResult to your Extension method, you can use -

```
MyActionResultVariable.ControllerName
```

Comment: This won't work - I need to call my extension method and *pass in* this data.

Comment: Let me give your one more answer in 5mins. I am working on it.

Comment: Check the alternate solution.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts, but I don't understand how this will help? In the extension method, I'll have an instance of an `ActionResult`. I need to extract the controller and action names from it, if possible (probably is, as T4MVC has a way of doing it). This new subclass means I'd need to change the method signatures of lots of controllers, and wouldn't be compatible with those overloads used by T4MVC anyway.

Comment: In that case why cant you just create a `ActionFilter`, in that set the `ViewBag` with current Controller and Action names.

Comment: I never use ViewBag. It's the worst.

Comment: I think maybe there is no answer... Thanks though! :)

Comment: This answer doesn't help me, but it does address the question nonetheless, and there are no other answers, so I'm accepting it. Thanks for trying to help.